# Confused on how to write my code as a function in python

Tags: python, vba

Hi everyone I'm still learning python 3 and I'm more familiar with VBA. I have the below python code and what it does is sort a csv file and save the conversion in a new file. Currently i can run this in idle and it works. I need to be able to define it as a function so i can call it from a vba button.

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
# file group_by_trailing_py2.py
import os
import csv
from itertools import groupby

DELIM=';'
IN_FILENAME = 'My Product.csv'
OUT_FILENAME = 'My Product.grouped.csv'


keyfunc = lambda row: row[1:]

with open(IN_FILENAME) as csv_file:
    ``rows = sorted(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM), key=keyfunc)

it = map(lambda t: [", ".join(v[0].strip() for v in t[1]) + " "] + t[0],
    groupby(rows, key=keyfunc))

with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM)  
for row in it:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f():
  DELIM=';'
  IN_FILENAME = 'My Product.csv'
  OUT_FILENAME = 'My Product.grouped.csv'


  keyfunc = lambda row: row[1:]
  with open(IN_FILENAME) as csv_file:
      ``rows = sorted(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM), key=keyfunc)

  it = map(lambda t: [", ".join(v[0].strip() for v in t[1]) + " "] + t[0],
      groupby(rows, key=keyfunc))

  with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM)  
  for row in it:
      writer.writerow(row) 

f()
```

Comment: So simple =) and it works your the best! @user2393267